# how to predict the sum of digits of the number $A(n)$ for a large natural $n$ without calculation, when $A(n)=a(n^2+n)+b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

look $A(n)=9n^2+9n-1$ , let $n=15233$ , $A(15233)=2088535697$

the sum of digits of this obtained number is :$53$ and always take this form :$9k+8$ , where $k=5$

and always exist a natural number $k$ give us the sum of digits of $A(n)$.

then without calculation we could predict this sum .

now I want some one show me if this is  true in the general for a number  $A(n)$ for large $n$ ?

I would be interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: It is farily easy to prove that we always have $S(A) = 9k+8$, but finding $k$ as a function of $n$ seems much more difficult. I think any 'formula' to do this would require the digits of $n$ as input...but then you could just sum them and get the answer straight away.

Comment: but i find a new way to predict it by only 3 possibility

Comment: but for example  n=153 , and other n= 100  , they haven't same , it's means no same k however both have same number of digits

Comment: Are you looking for just a proof that $S(A) = 9k+8$ for some $k$? Or do you want a proof that no two $S(A),S(B)$ have the same $k$ value?

Comment: I look the 2 cases , it's well for me  to know how we get a few possibility to get k  ?

Comment: The way that I have to get k for any large number always i have 3 possibilities but i can't get exact value of k directly .

Comment: Why don't you edit the question explaining your method to get the three possibilities and maybe someone will see a way to help you.

Comment: ok, thank you very much , i will edit it 2rr

Comment: i think if i get the exact value of k , it's will be important for me about number theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can predict the exact digit sum, but working out the digital root (also known as the repeated digital sum) can at least help narrow down the possibilities.

The digital root is similar to the digital sum, except that you repeat the process until you get a single digit number. 2,088,535,697 = 2 + 0 + 8 + 8 + 5 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 7 = 53, and 5 + 3 = 8. Therefore, 8 is the digital root of 2,088,535,697.

Let's define A(n) = 7n<sup>2</sup> + 7n - 5, and we'll let n be 41,381.

First, let's find the digital root of n. 4 + 1 + 3 + 8 + 1 = 17, and 1 + 7 = 8, so the digital root is 8.

Instead of calculating A(41,381), we'll calculate A(8). So, A(8) = 7(8<sup>2</sup>) + 7(8) - 5 = 7(64) + 56 - 5 = 448 + 56 - 5 = 448 + 51 = 499.

Next, we find the digital root of that answer. 4 + 9 + 9 = 22, and 2 + 2 = 4. Now we know that, regardless of the exact result of A(41,381), the answer must have a digital root of 4.

What else do we know? Well, we're squaring a 5-digit number, so A(n) can only be a 9- or 10-digit number. Let's check out the digital sums (not digital roots this time, but digital *sums*) of the extreme possibilities here.

The smallest 9-digit number, of course, is 100,000,000, with a digital sum of 1. The largest 10-digit number is 9,999,999,999, with a digital sum of 90.

This, then, narrows down all the possibilities quite a ways. The digital sum can only range from 1 to 90, and the digital root of the sum must be 4. The only numbers from 1 through 90 which qualify are 4, 13, 22, 31, 40, 49, 58, 67, 76, and 85. The digital sum, then, *MUST* be one of those.

Let's see if this is right by actually working through the full calculation. A(41,381) = 11,986,999,789. 1 + 1 + 9 + 8 + 6 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 76.

Although I didn't predict 76 on its own, I did include 76 as one of only 10 possibilities!

**EXTRA NOTES:** Some special cases are handled more easily than others, too. I can look at your particular example of A(n) = 9n<sup>2</sup> + 9n - 1, and know instantly that every result will have a digital root of 8.

How?

Since n<sup>2</sup> and n are both multiplied by 9, they'll have a digital root of 9. [Any number multiplied by 9 will always have a digital root of 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q53GmMCqmAM). So, the only thing left to change the digital root is the + b.

When A(n) = 9n<sup>2</sup> + 9n - 1, the digital root is going to be 1 less than a multiple of 9, or 8. If a remains 9 and b is changed to +5, then the digital root of any answer in that problem would be 5.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer , but for ur example : 7n²+7n-1, the sum of digits of number take this form :7k+6 or 7k-1, always k exist .k is natural number .but i could predict any sum with only 3 possibilities using just the number of digits of n .